# How to send wiremock stub responses driven by header value

Tags: wiremock

I need to build a stub with wiremock and have it return a response or another based on a certain header using a simple rule:

- if the header starts with 400 sed back a `Bad Request` response
- if the header starts with 500 send back an `Internal Server Error` response
- for any other headers send back an `Accepted` response

```
    {
      "request": {
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "urlPattern": "/v1/my/path"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "bodyFileName": "files/{{request.headers.<first.three.characers.of.my.header matching 400/500 or 202 otherwise>}}-response.json"
      }
    }
```

Thanks you in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted only a single mapping, then you'd have to write a custom extension to achieve that. I don't believe there is intelligent enough parsing to only return the first three characters. Additionally, you'd need to have a JSON file for each status code that could potentially be sent in the header.

Instead, you could have three separate mappings that contain the matching you want.

```json
{
    "priority": 1,
    "request": {
        "url": "/some/path",
        "headers": {
            "some-header": {
                "matches": "400.*"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 400,
        "bodyFileName": "some-400-response.json",
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "priority": 1,
    "request": {
        "url": "/some/path",
        "headers": {
            "some-header": {
                "matches": "500.*"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 500,
        "bodyFileName": "some-500-response.json",
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "priority": 2,
    "request": {
        "url": "/some/path"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "some-other-response.json",
    }
}
```

The two major things happening in these mappings are:

- using priority (1 for the specific 400/500 cases, 2 for the general case)
- matching on header value (regex matching on the first three characters and then (.*) for the rest of the header)

Comment: That will work. The only issue is that I had to support a few types of 400 (401, 403, etc) as well as a few 500 and that will result in a big number of mapping files. Not sure if possible to capture the first three characters of the header (\\d\\d\\d).* and use that as the response file name. Any idea if that is doable. I could see that type of usage in the url pattern: `v1/users/(\\d+)/internal/preferences/([^\\s]+)`

Comment: I'm not certain on this, but I don't think that the Handlebars language supports substrings naturally. If you wanted to support all of the different 400 types, you could either manually change the request header matching to specifically target 400/402/etc. Or, you could write a custom response extension that picks the header apart for you and returns the bodyFileName with the 40* value.