# Creating mock OAuth server with preset tokens

Tags: docker, testing, docker-compose, oauth-2.0, mocking

I am authenticating users on my Flask API by using an external OAuth server which stores tokens, I then introspect tokens to my API by asking the external server to introspect it. I now want to test my functionality, but don't want to use the external server in my test. Therefor I want to host an OAuth server locally for tests. The only thing I want to do in this server is introspect. Is it possible to somehow host an OAuth server with some set tokens, client_id, client_secret so I can complete this example code:

```py
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/introspect"
payload = {
    "token": "tokentokentoken",
    'token_type_hint': 'access_token'
}

# Make a POST request to the specified URL with the payload
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=("myClientID", "secret"))

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Print the token received in the response
    print("Token:", response.json().get("token"))
else:
    # Print an error message if the request was not successful
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

I already tried this docker image https://github.com/navikt/mock-oauth2-server but I don't seem to figure out how I can have a preset token, client_id and client_secret.

Comment: Your question seems to be _"can I have a local server that responds to a POST request to a single endpoint?"_, in which case the answer is: yes, of course. FWIW I wrote some of a mock OAuth server [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fauxauth), it's not a very complicated protocol.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your response! That's correct. Only with the detail that I want some preset tokens. In my case corresponding to 3 different roles, a user, admin and mod. In my test I can than use these tokens to identify myself as one of these roles. Associated with these tokens I also want the `uid` to be returned. I see that configuring preset tokens is possible with your mock server, but is there an introspect endpoint? Or is there another way to achieve the following? Please keep in mind this is my first time using OAuth. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a mock HTTP server that returns canned introspection responses for particular mock opaque tokens provided as input. One way to do this is to use the Wiremock tool.

There is an endpoint that you could use to register expected responses based on incoming header values. Example usage is published in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219801/how-to-send-wiremock-stub-responses-driven-by-header-value).

For an example that deals with some of the technical setup you could take a look at this Node.js example code of mine. The concepts are easily portable to any other API programming language.

- [Test code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/test/integrationTests.ts#L210)
- [HTTP setup](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/test/utils/mockAuthorizationServer.ts#L30)